# calculate number of days in ajax calender extender

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I want to calculate the number of days in asp.net by AJAX calender extender on text box. But i am not getting the right output which i want. I can't find the error which is coming in output. The code is

```
    string a = TextBox1.Text;
    string b = TextBox2.Text;
    DateTime t1 = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
    DateTime t2 = Convert.ToDateTime(b);
    TimeSpan days = t2 - t1;
    int zile = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(365-(days.TotalDays)));
    TextBox3.Text = zile.ToString();
```

I am not getting the right output.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you are calculating the days difference in the code behind file. You can calculate it easily like below.

```
TimeSpan diff = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text));
int noOfDays = diff.Days + 1;
```

Comment: it is not working well. it is giving the number of days from 1 January to till October.

Comment: @user1648801, can you give the dateformat of your calendar extender. And tell me what is your input dates and your expected result.